# smooth scroll when using flexbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flexbox, smooth-scrolling

I have a page that the primary content is using `display: flex`,

```
.outer-wrap .inner-wrap {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    margin-left: -280px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The problem is that all of the smooth scrolling JS/JQuery I have tried do not scroll smoothly.

The JS I am trying to use is,

```
var $root = $('html, body');

$('.sideNav-link').click(function() {
    var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
    $root.animate({
        scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
    }, 500, function () {
        window.location.hash = href;
    });
    return false;
});
```

How can I use this when also using `display: flex`?

**UPDATE**: 
Adding fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/sLe2699u/3/

It looks like the issue is the `height: 100%` on the html, body. How can I have my pages be full screen without this but still have the smooth scrolling?

Comment: Where is your HTML ?

Comment: Then create a minimum viable example. Otherwise it's impossible to guess where the issue lies.

Comment: I have created a fiddle and updated the OP. Thanks in advance for taking a look!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to scroll the `html` and `body` elements, but these are not scrollable because everything fits inside them. The element that is actually hiding something is `.main-content`, thus that is the element to scroll in this case.

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('.main-content').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```